# Highchart pie legend circles

Tags: javascript, highcharts, geometry, legend

Im using a highchart pie chart to create a donut chart but would like the legend icons to be circles any ideas??? Below is the mockup and the actual web version. Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prepared solution based on pie chart. Legend is generated on data points, automatically as HTML list. Then all elements gets colors from series, and use CSS3 to generate circle object (border-radius). As a result you need to add click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

```
 $legend = $('#customLegend');

    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (j, data) {

        $legend.append('<div class="item"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:'+data.color+'"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' + data.name + '</div></div>');

    });

    $('#customLegend .item').click(function(){
        var inx = $(this).index(),
            point = chart.series[0].data[inx];

        if(point.visible)
            point.setVisible(false);
        else
            point.setVisible(true);
    });
```

CSS:

```
    .symbol {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.serieName {
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.item {
    height:40px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of Highcharts you can use `symbolWidth: width` and `symbolRadius: width/2` inside `legend: {}`.

See this JSFiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Wzs9L/

Comment: So clean and effective. Excellent.

Comment: @walterpaoli how to change the legend to rectangle from circle it will be helpful if you can provide this. Thanks!

Comment: you could set symbolRadius to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this can be overriding the style using CSS.
Simply add class below to your stylesheet:

```
.highcharts-legend-item rect {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px; /* height = width */
    rx: 50%;
    ry: 50%;
}
```

and this would override the default style for the SVG Rectangle element.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite an easy fix. Just set the following properties in chartoptions:

```
chartoptions.legend.symbolHeight = 12;
chartoptions.legend.symbolWidth = 12;
chartoptions.legend.symbolRadius = 6;
```

For further reference, check [highcharts api documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.symbolRadius).

Checkout this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/symbolradius/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider [How do I write a good answer? – Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).