# Changing Legend symbol Highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to make the legend symbol as circles instead of rectangles in my highchart areachart, how to customize the shape of legend symbol?

Comment: I advice to famliar with the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041490/highchart-pie-legend-circles/17047489#17047489

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's an easy fix for this.  One hack that's been around for a while, is to link your area series with an empty scatter series (scatter series will use the symbol in the legend):

```
{
    data: [],
    name: 'USA',
    type: 'scatter',
    color: 'rgb(47,126,216)',
    marker: {
        symbol: 'circle'
    }
},
{
    name: 'USA',
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6 , 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
        1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
        27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
        26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
        24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
        22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
        10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 ],
    linkedTo: ':previous'
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rEg38/).