# Add a class to highcharts pie chart section

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart pie chart and a table to the right of the pie chart which displays the data in table form.

I would like to link the table with the pie chart so that when I hover over a row in the table it will be as if I am hovering over the pie chart segment.

I believe to do this I would need to add a class to the pie chart segment/path that I can then call using JS when hovering over the table row.

What would be the best way to either achieve this?

(I know it's possible to have a basic legend attached to the pie chart but because I need the table to be in a bootstrap column to the right along with some other data the legend isn't enough :) ).

Here is the current chart setup:

```
<!-- in Page JS --> 
  <script>

    $(function () { 
      $('#results_donut').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: false
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            shadow: false,
          },
          series: {
            states: {
              hover: {
                enabled: false
              }
            },
            point: {
              events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                  this.options.oldColor = this.color;
                  this.graphic.attr("fill", "#F8464A");
                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                  this.graphic.attr("fill", this.options.oldColor);
                }
              }
            },
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false,
          formatter: function() {
            return this.point.name + ': ' + this.y +' %';
          },
          style: {
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            fontWeight: '300',
            letterSpacing: '0.03em',
            fontSize: '14px'
          },
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Failure Reasons',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [["Brakes",74.6],["Seatbelts", 19.4]],
        }],
      });
    });

  </script>
```

And here is the view code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div id="results_donut"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 result-figures">
    <div class="row failure-reasons">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4>Failure Reasons</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-6 text-uppercase failure-name">Brakes</td>
              <td class="col-xs-2">74.6%</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a class="transition" href="#">View Details</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-6 text-uppercase failure-name">Seatbelts</td>
              <td class="col-xs-2">19.4%</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a class="transition" href="#">View Details</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not make any assumptions like if you are hovering the i-th row of the table, that is the i-th pie slice?

Comment: mmm good idea, I hadn't thought of that :). Do you know the JS to get it working taking this approach? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041490/highchart-pie-legend-circles/17047489#17047489) question has some answers for your case.